# Locking variables in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, mutex

I'm making a Windows Gadget where I get data from multiple URLs using "ActiveXObject"s. I've heard that JavaScript is single-threaded but ActiveXObjects run in parallel and they modify the `news` variable which causes errors. Is there a way to lock a variable so that I can prevent this?

By the way, I tried `xmlDocument.async = false` and it works but it introduces too much delay. I'm looking for an alternative.

My code:

```
for(var i = 0; i < noFeeds; i++){
    var URL = System.Gadget.Settings.readString("feedURL"+i);
    var xmlDocument = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM');

    xmlDocument.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(xmlDocument.readyState == 4){
            if( xmlDocument.getElementsByTagName("item").length != 0 )
                RSSChannel(xmlDocument, news);
            else
                AtomChannel(xmlDocument, news);
        }
    };
    xmlDocument.load(URL);
}
```

Comment: Give them a cloned object instead?

Comment: `ActiveXObjects run in parallel` -- Do you have any documentation supporting this statement? (That they run the `onreadystatechange` event on different threads) I can't find any, but I didn't look for long.

Comment: This page tells about `async` of ActiveXObjects:
http://www.w3schools.com/dom/prop_document_async.asp